# Android Game: global high score system?

Tags: android

Is there a simple way, to store my games high scores in a global score system? 
I tried OpenFeint, but it has very poor sample, and not working. (or it is difficult for me)

Is there a simplied system right now? Or any tutorial on this?

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [ScoreNinja](http://scoreninja.appspot.com/)

Comment: After using a bunch of the different options in my games, I've found that Swarm (aka SwarmConnect) has great docs, runs wicked fast, and has a very complete feature set for Android game developers.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but also check out [Swarm's Leaderboards](http://swarmconnect.com/leaderboards) system, similar to OpenFeint/ScoreLoop/ScoreNinja, but faster and has amazing docs and examples :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Skiller](http://www.skiller-games.com) to manage my leader-boards, and it worked great. You can define your own leader-boards (for example: the fastest player or the player that reached the highest score..).
It's really simple.

Hope i helped.