# Tutorial for Global High scores in Android?

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for setting up global high scores in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Game: global high score system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513246/android-game-global-high-score-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swarm is a great, simple option as well.  Implementation is a total breeze.  http://swarmconnect.com

Comment: Thanks, It took like 5 minutes to implement, very simple!

Answer (score 1):

Try [ScoreNinja](http://scoreninja.appspot.com/)

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513631/1426079)

Comment: I've tried it, The only problem is, The player needs to download a whole new app just to view high scores.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific tutorial, but a simple high level way of doing it would be so:

```
-Server will hold the high score values
-User will play and achieve a score
-User then downloads the current high score from server
-If current score is higher, replace database value.
```

Of course it gets more complicated than that.  You would need some way to make sure that concurrent access to a high score doesn't have the wrong high score being written to the server in the end.  But I think it would be a good start to just research those points independently.  Not sure if you were looking to do this yourself or just find a service to implement it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Parse](http://parse.com).

They basically take care of everything for you.